# Flutter SharedPrefs Cubit InitState is ... strange

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, bloc, cubit

You can see the strange behaviour in this video: https://streamable.com/r5ld2y

The InitValue is the correct one, but when I restart the App it first goes to zero, AFTER loading the Screen OR press a button, it loads the shared prefs...

This is my Cubit (Only with the LoadCounter Func):

```
class DrinkCubit extends Cubit<DrinkState> {
  DrinkCubit() : super(DrinkState(drinkValue: 0));

  Future<void> loadCounter() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    state.drinkValue = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
  }
}
```

And this is my InitFunction in the main window!

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,()
    {
      BlocProvider.of<DrinkCubit>(context).loadCounter();
    });
  }
```

So how do I fix this, that the correct value is directly after starting the app showed

Comment: I want that the Init State with the value from shared prefs loads directly, onStartup.

Comment: You have to emit updated state after setting 'state.drinkValue'

Comment: you answere fixed it, great job. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getData(){
  BlocProvider.of<DrinkCubit>(context).loadCounter();
}


@override
void initState() {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    getData();
  });

 super.initState();
}
```

SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback ensures that code inside run before UI code.

And if it allows me to give you a hint, is better remove SharedPreferences of your Bloc and put in another class.

Comment: This alone didnt fixed it, but in combination with :   `Future<void> loadCounter() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    state.drinkValue = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    emit(DrinkState(drinkValue: state.drinkValue));
  }`'
And I am new to Bloc so yet, i dont know how to put in in another class :D